# DotNetOpenAuth ReturnToUrl not working

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I'm new to DotNetOpenAuth. I've managed to do login using google & yahoo. However, I'm not able to get ReturnToUrl to work. Here is my markup:

No matter what I do, it redirects back to the homepage on login. I've tried doing it OnInit, but it's still not picking. Is there any other overriding property somewhere I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ReturnToUrl should be your login page.  That's where the OpenID assertion is sent.  If you want to control where the user goes *after* login has completed, you should change your web.config setting:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms defaultUrl="your-desired-user-landing-page-here"/>
    </authentication>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Can't we do it with code. I am using http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/developers/code-snippets/programmatic-openid-relying-party/ code snippet in my Login.aspx page but it is returning to default.aspx page which is not exist.

Comment: Yes. You can call `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthTicket` and then redirect the user anywhere you want.